# What test can you use to prove convergence/divergence?

Tags: calculus

I tried to use the comparison test on this series however it oscillates above and below $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, which violates the constraints of the comparison test. Any help would be much appreciated.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{n}}{n^{2}} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the theorem that if a series converges absolutely, then it converges. (The term "converges absolutely" makes the theorem sound more obvious than it is.)

Now Comparison does it. Our series converges absolutely, that is, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\cos n|}{n^2}$ converges, by the Comparison Test. For note that $0\le |\cos n|\le 1$ for all $n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, because $-1 \le \cos n \le 1$, $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{\cos n}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$.

So if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges,

> It does converge. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n^2}$, which is bounded above and below, should converge as well.

Comment: This is an application of the squeeze theorem no?

Comment: This is manifestly false. $\sum (-1)^n$ is bounded above and below, but doesn't converge.

Comment: But this expression doesn't involve any summation of $(-1)^n$.

Comment: You're claiming that if the partial sums of an *arbitrary* series are bounded, then the series converges. This is false.