# Show that sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to show, that this sum is convergent. My book suggest me the following solutions, but I think it's not a correct. Can somebody explain me, whether I am right or not?

$$s:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$$

It's clearly that $\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Therefore if we apply $\textbf{Comparison Test}$ we will get it. But I think, we can't not apply this theorem here! Because Comparison Test requires that both sequences $0 \leq x_n \leq y_n$ are nonnegative, but $\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$ can be negative, for example for $n=91$, so we can not apply this theorem for this series. Am I right? If yes, how can I prove, that this sum converges? All theorems, which I know, require that my sequence have to be nonnegative.

Comment: [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) implies convergence

Comment: Think about the triangle inequality.

Comment: Take absolute values. $|\cos(n)/n^2|<1/n^2$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for your answer. But am I right? We can not apply this theorem without using, what you suggested. Because one of condition is not true?

Comment: @mathguruu that is right. You cannot directly apply the comparison test

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thank you) its what I wanted to know)

Comment: It depends what you call [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)

Comment: @AnneBauval definiton from your link also requires that both sequences are nonnegative))

Comment: @mathguruu my link says next "Alternatively, the test may be stated in terms of absolute convergence, in which case it also applies to series with complex terms [...]" Anyway, if the only question of this post is "can I apply a theorem when its hypothesis are not fulfilled", I don't find it worthwile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What test can you use to prove convergence/divergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773430/what-test-can-you-use-to-prove-convergence-divergence)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yes, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Note:
$$\left|\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
But, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so also $\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent. By the absolute convergence theorem, we get that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{cos(n)}{n^2}$ converges.